# Kafka metrics attribute meaning and unit

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics, mbeans

I use JMX server to get metrics data for Kafka, but I am confused about some attributes. For example, the object *`kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec,request=FetchFollower`*
 has attributes `Count` and `MeanRate`.

The `Count` attribute seems to be the value of the `FetchFollower` metric, but I found it ascending, so I guess it is the aggregate value.

What is the `MeanRate` attribute? Is it the current rate for `FetchFollower`? And what is the unit here: byte, kbyte, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `RequestsPerSec` suggests, the unit measured is the number of requests by FetchFollowers per sec. The `MeanRate` is the average FetchFollower-requests/sec rate since the broker first went up, so no, it's not current.

You're right about the `Count` metric--it's the aggregate number of FetchFollower requests, so to get the current rate, you should calculate the `Count` difference over a window of time.

Comment: Like I said, the unit is 'requests/sec' for `MeanRate` and just 'requests' for `Count`.

Comment: Is there any broker level metrics to get the `FetchFollower` network IO? Something like `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesOut/InPerSec`

Comment: Not that I know off the top of my head. Post another question if you're interested and I'm sure someone can help you.